# Process NA in a specific way with aggregate function

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Project Week Number
Project1   01  46.0
Project2   01  46.4
Project3   01 105.0
Project1   02  70.0
Project2   02  84.0
Project3   02  34.8
Project1   03  83.0
Project3   03  37.9
```

**Edit:**

```
> dput(my.df)
structure(list(Project = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("Project1", "Project2", "Project3"), class = "factor"), 
    Week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Number = c(46, 
    46.4, 105, 70, 84, 34.8, 83, 37.9)), .Names = c("Project", 
"Week", "Number"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L
))
```

I want to compute the sum for each project for each week.

So I use the aggregate function:

```
aggregate(Number ~ Project + Week, data = my.df, sum)
```

As you can see, there is no value for the Project2 in Week 3.

Using the aggregate function just leaves it blank.
What I want is to have the line filled in with 0.

I tried:

```
aggregate(Number ~ Project + Week, data = my.df, sum, na.action = 0)
```

and

```
aggregate(Number ~ Project + Week, data = my.df, sum, na.action = function(x) 0)
```

But none work.
Any idea?

Comment: Please show your data using `dput()`

Comment: well, agregation functions do not create magically data that is not present in the first place! :-) you need first to explicitely create the line of missing combinations, or merge the output with a data.Frame containing all the combinations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xtabs()`:

```
my.df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
'Project Week Number
Project1   01  46.0
Project2   01  46.4
Project3   01 105.0
Project1   02  70.0
Project2   02  84.0
Project3   02  34.8
Project1   03  83.0
Project3   03  37.9')
my.df$Week <- paste0("0", my.df$Week)

xtabs(Number ~ Project+Week, data=my.df)
#           Week
# Project       01    02    03
#   Project1  46.0  70.0  83.0
#   Project2  46.4  84.0   0.0
#   Project3 105.0  34.8  37.9
as.data.frame(xtabs(Number ~ Project+Week, data=my.df))
#    Project Week  Freq
# 1 Project1   01  46.0
# 2 Project2   01  46.4
# 3 Project3   01 105.0
# 4 Project1   02  70.0
# 5 Project2   02  84.0
# 6 Project3   02  34.8
# 7 Project1   03  83.0
# 8 Project2   03   0.0
# 9 Project3   03  37.9
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also use the `complete` function from the `tidyr` package to fill in the value of `Project2` in `Week 3`. After that, we can aggregate the data.

```
library(tidyr)

my.df2 <- my.df %>% 
  complete(Project, Week, fill = list(Number = 0))

my.df2

# # A tibble: 9 x 3
#    Project  Week Number
#      <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1 Project1    01   46.0
# 2 Project1    02   70.0
# 3 Project1    03   83.0
# 4 Project2    01   46.4
# 5 Project2    02   84.0
# 6 Project2    03    0.0
# 7 Project3    01  105.0
# 8 Project3    02   34.8
# 9 Project3    03   37.9
```

**DATA**

```
my.df <- read.table(text = "Project Week Number
Project1   '01'  46.0
                 Project2   01  46.4
                 Project3   01 105.0
                 Project1   02  70.0
                 Project2   02  84.0
                 Project3   02  34.8
                 Project1   03  83.0
                 Project3   03  37.9",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my.df$Week <- paste0("0", my.df$Week)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `spread` from `tidyr` with `fill = 0`

```
aggregate(Number ~ Project + Week, data = my.df, sum) %>% 
  spread(key = Week,value = Number,fill = 0)
```

and then use gather to get it back to your original form

```
aggregate(Number ~ Project + Week, data = my.df, sum) %>% 
  spread(key = Week,value = Number,fill = 0) %>% 
  gather(key = Week, value = Number,`1`,`2`,`3`)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in base R, it's pretty much `tidyr::complete` 's code translated in base R (see @www's answer).

```
df <- merge(
  setNames(expand.grid(unique(df$Project),unique(df$Week)),c("Project","Week")),
  df, all.x=TRUE)
df$Number[is.na(df$Number)] <- 0
```